# Is there an equivalent of the Bandit package in r (Used in implementation of Multi arm bandit algorithm) in python?

Tags: r, python, predictive-modeling

I want to implement MAB(Multi arm bandit algorithm ) in python. There is a package called bandit in R [Check here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bandit/bandit.pdf), is there anything similar to this in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check this one from a [book](https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/BanditsBook) on MAB
- There's also a [flask](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-MAB/)implementation if you want a web service

Comment: Bandit package takes 2 inputs trials and successes and based on that gives me a probability of success of a arm. I couldn't figure how to modify the code in the book to this. ( i am a newbie, a little help would be useful)

Comment: @karan please specifiy exactly what portion of the code you did not follow and an example of what you have tried out

Comment: The current implementation involves randomly choosing an arm and recording the reward. But my problem statement is  - n ads are running with each of budget B. Now i want to re -distribute budget nB among n ads based on the success probability of ad. (prob can be calculated with revenue and trial metric of each ad)